# Can I run games like Minecraft on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, minecraft

I just bought a pretty powerful server that will be mainly used for webhosting. I thought about installing Ubuntu Server because I like that it doesn't have a real UI. But because the server is so powerful, I'd really like to see how playing games like Minecraft would be on it.
So I know Ubuntu Server doesn't have a grafical interface, but can it display games, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, no. All modern games rely on there being a GUI present, otherwise they'll fail to execute. You'd have to install a desktop and other packages to get a GUI running. `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` should automatically install GNOME3 and the default packages you get installing normally. If you want to choose and pick what you want and keep it 
very minimal you can run `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop`. This should work, but don't quote me. I'd suggest backing stuff up in case if stuff breaks.

There's also a list of alternative desktop environments you can install, I'm not 100% sure if they'll provide needed packages, so use `apt show packagenamehere` for details and install what's needed. This list doesn't cover all of them.

XFCE: `sudo apt install xfce4`

LXDE: `sudo apt install lxde`

KDE (might be unstable): `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop`

TL;DR `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` should install everything provided in a default install, though `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop` might work for servers better as everything isn't installed at once and you can pick what to install.

I've never tried this personally so I cannot guarantee if this will work perfectly, again, backups are key.

Answer (score 0):

Can I run games like Minecraft on Ubuntu Server? Yes, depending on the game.

For example, you can do something like this:

```
$ ssh -X user@ubuntuserver
$ minetest
```

(you probably want to do `sudo apt-get install minetest` first)

The experience varies a lot, depending on the game, the need for acceleration and the quality of the network link for example.

Another alternative is to use a remote session, like `vncserver` and then connect from the computer where you actually have the screen.